# remove stopwords from pandas df with user-supplied list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, stop-words

I have a raw_corpus and am trying to delete stopwords with a user-defined stoplist (I edited the nltk english stopwords file). Something must be wrong with my stopwords file?

Here's the input pandas df raw_corpus:

[image: raw_corpus]

Here's my code:

```
#my own custom stopwords list
stoplist="/User/dlhoffman/nltk_data/corpora/stopwords/english"
#filter out stopwords
raw_corpus['constructed_recipe'] = raw_corpus['constructed_recipe'].apply(lambda x: [item for item in x if 
item not in stoplist])
#running the code below verifies empty dataframe
#raw_corpus['constructed_recipe'] = raw_corpus['constructed_recipe'].apply(lambda x: [])
```

Here's the result - obviously not what I'm looking for! what's wrong?:

[image: output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[pd.Series.apply](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) with a generator expression should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

df = pd.DataFrame([['this is the first test string'],
                   ['this is yet another test'],
                   ['this is a third test item'],
                   ['this is the final test string']],
                  columns=['String'])

replace_set = {'this', 'is'}

df['String'] = df['String'].str.split(' ').apply(lambda x: ' '.join(k for k in x if k not in replace_set))

# df
#                     String
# 0    the first test string
# 1         yet another test
# 2        a third test item
# 3    the final test string
```

**Explanation**

- `pd.Series.str.split` splits words by whitespace, returning a series of lists, with each list item a word.
- `pd.Series.apply` accepts a `lambda` (anonymous) function as an input, effectively applying a function to each item in the series in a loop.
- The generator expression `(k for k in x if k not in replace_set)` returns each value of `k` as an iterable subject to the `if` condition.
- `' '.join` is used on the generator expression to form a string from the generated words.

Comment: That makes sense. I showed the code above to a colleague and he said that if I tokenize first it would work. True? I do tokenize, but later. So is that the problem? The apply method has no way of knowing what a word is?  Your method above takes care of that, right? So that's another way to go.

Comment: Your attempt is cycling through strings one letter at a time: `[item for item in x if item not in stoplist]`. When you iterate a string, you are looking at each element individually. Instead you need to be looking for stopwords within your string and replace them with an empty string ''. `re.sub` does this functionally.

Comment: @profhoff Indeed, apply method has no concept of words, it just applies some logic to each string in the column. The downside with this method is you may end up with double spaces, but that's easily correctable (if it is an issue).

Comment: Ah! Thanks for the quick help.

Comment: Still doesn't work. :(   It looks like apply function doesn't understand that each of my tokens is a word - so it's pulling out the stopwords from each word. Not sure how to fix that:    e.g. weather weather sunrise create a status message facebook social networks becomes  --> ['wer', 'wer', 'unre', 'ce', '', 'u', 'ege', 'fcebk', 'cl', 'newrk']

Comment: @profhoff, this version splits by ' ' to check for word matches.

Comment: There may still be issues with punctation, e.g. "somestring," would not match stopword "somestring", but given your data sample this may not be an issue.

Comment: jpp - works but why? all the examples of stopword removal look very similar but don't work on my pandas df. is that because they are meant for a numpy array or a list or some other data structure?

Comment: excellent! now the advanced datacamp tutorials are starting to click...